# Why I get urllib2.HTTPError with urllib2 and no errors with urllib?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I have the following simple code:

```
import urllib2
import sys
sys.path.append('../BeautifulSoup/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1')
from BeautifulSoup import *
page='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
```

This code generates the following error messages:

```
    c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 130, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 364, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 471, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 402, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 337, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 480, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

But if I replace urllib2 by urllib, I get no error messages. Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original `urllib` simply does not raise an exception on a 403 code.  If you add `print c.getcode()` to the last line of your program, `urllib` will reach it and still print out 403.

Then if you do `print c.read()` at the end, you will see that you did indeed get an error page from Wikipedia.  It's just a matter of `urllib2` deciding to treat an error 403 as a runtime exception, versus `urllib` allowing you to still get an error 403 and then do something with the page.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia seems to be filtering out urllib2's default User-Agent. Just change it.

Answer (score 0):

[Overriding urllib2.HTTPError or urllib.error.HTTPError and reading response HTML anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233687/overriding-urllib2-httperror-and-reading-response-html-anyway) this post shows some nice way to obtain detailed error message from server