# urllib2: Fetch URL content even on Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I'm sending a `POST` request to some URL and this URL then throws a `200 OK` or `401 Unauthorized` code depending on the parameters provided in the `POST` request.

Additionally to that return code, the website also returns a text, which is especially useful on errors so the person who did the request knows why it failed. For that, I use this code:

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://site/request'
params = {
  'param1': 'value1',
  'param2': 'value2',
  ...
}

data = urllib.urlencode(params)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)

try:
  response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  the_page = response.read()
except urllib2.URLError as e:
  print e.code, e.reason  # Returns only 401 Unauthorized, not the text
```

When the request is successful, I get a `200` code and I can grab the message with the `the_page` variable. Pretty useless in that case.

But when it fails, the line which throws the `URLError` is the one calling `urlopen()`, so I can't grab the web error message.

Is there any way to grab the message even on a `URLError` event? If not, is there an alternative way to do a `POST` request and grab the Web content on error?

The Python version is `2.7.6` in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you catch an HTTPError—it’s a more specific subclass of URLError and I think it would be raised in case of a 401—it can be read as a file-like object, yielding page contents:

- [`urllib2.HTTPError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError) documentation
- [Overriding urllib2.HTTPError or urllib.error.HTTPError and reading response HTML anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233687/overriding-urllib2-httperror-and-reading-response-html-anyway)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the requests library (install using `pip install requests`)

```
import requests
url = 'https://site/request'
params = {
  'param1': 'value1',
  'param2': 'value2',
}
post_response = requests.post(url, json=params)


if post_response.ok:
    the_page = post_response.content
    # do your stuff here

print post_response.content  # this will give you the message regardless of failure
print post_response.status_code  # this will give you the status code of the request
post_response.raise_for_status()  # this will throw an error if the status is not 200
```

Docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/